# LINQ to SQL multiple tables left outer join w/condition in 'on' clause

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

```
SELECT u.username, COUNT(r.id)
FROM users u
         LEFT JOIN userroles ur ON u.id = ur.userid
         LEFT JOIN roles r ON ur.roleid = r.id AND r.name = 'Managers'
GROUP BY u.username
ORDER BY u.username
```

The goal is very simple, the above SQL runs fine, now I need to figure out how to convert it into LINQ code.  I have the left joins working, the two things I don't know how to do is the count and the r.name = 'Managers'.  Here is what I have so far, how do I finish it off?

```
var result =
    from user in _context.Users
    join userRole in _context.UserRoles on user.Id equals userRole.UserId into userUserRoleGroup
    from u in userUserRoleGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join role in _context.Roles
        on u.RoleId equals role.Id into roleUserRoleGroup
    from r in roleUserRoleGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new UserRole { Username = user.UserName, RoleName = r.Name };
```

Comment: Begin by using navigation properties instead of `join`. Then, try to forget the SQL statement. Try to get the info you want by writing LINQ. Also, it's either linq-to-sql or linq-to-entities, not both. Probably the latter, and then the exact version matters.

Comment: I simply cannot wrap my head around "use navigation properties instead of join", could you provide an example?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships

Comment: You know what, it is late on a Friday, I have to get this done, my head hurts, is there any way you can have some mercy on me and not make to rethink the whole thing and just help me with the answer?

Comment: Maybe, for the time being, first get the manager role's Id, then `_context.Users.Select(u => new { u.Name, Count = _context.UserRoles.Count(ur =>  u.Id == ur.UserId && ur.RoleId == managerId) })`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the count like this:

```
var count = from role in _context.Role
            group role by role.UserId into groupedRoles
            select new
            {
                 RoleId = groupedRoles.Key,
                 Total = groupedRoles.Count()
            }
```

and then you can join the variable "count" in your query.
It will have the property "Total" that is your count.